# How can I make that when someone clicks on a share icon that it shares the property image with the URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

so I set up a property listing website with the WordPress theme/platform called RealHomes.

here is the website link: https://www.propertytrail.co.za

When viewing a property you can share that property to social media via the share icons. But when you share the property it only shares the URL and the website icon.

I want the specific thumbnail of that property to be shared with the URL. Not the website Logo.

I've looked around in the Theme Editor, but I can't find the share widget, but I might just be missing it.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without touching your any code.

Install the following plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/autodescription/

Wherever you want to add the image go to that post or page.

Scroll down to find Page SEO Settings tab.

Add image in Social Image URL : [image]

Save the post. You can now share the page and the image you uploaded will be used as the thumbnail.

These basically add OG tags to your page. Read about them here : https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/o/open-graph.htm

Comment: @ChristiaanKühn Great. You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. It explains what can you do when someone answers your question. Welcome to the community.